# Как убрать ошибку выделение памяти в С90

Tags: c, gcc, clion

Компилятор выдал **Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)**, если не ставить настройки в gnu gcc compiler такие как на фото
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это настройки в компиляторе Code::Blocks, в Clion если ставить проект C90, та же ошибка.

Читал данные из файла data.txt c таким по формату содержанием для занесения в линейный односвязный список

*Chevrolet Aveo (T250);Chevrolet;500;6;1568.6;350.12;20;45;75;90;120;180;*

*Skoda Kamiq;Skoda;1000;6;1570.5;6450;15;30;55;80;110;200;*

*Honda Ridgeline;Honda;1500;6;2000;17887.5;20;40;80;120;150;180;*

*Lexus NX;Lexus;750;5;2265.23;82812.5;30;60;80;120;200;**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct cars {
    int id; //ID
    char *name;// потом динамически выделяется память под имя
    char *producer;// та же песня
    int max_load;//макс нагрузка
    int count_gears;//кол-во передач
    float weight;//вес
    float price;//цена
    int *max_speed_grear;//массив с макс скоростями для каждой передачи
    struct cars *next;//указатель на следующий элемент списка
} cr;

typedef struct head {
    int count;//количество элементов всего
    cr *first;//указатель на первый элемент списка
    cr *last;//на последний элемент список
} head;

head *make_head() {
    head *ph = NULL;

    ph = (head*)malloc(sizeof(head));
    if (ph) {
        ph->count = 0;
        ph->first = NULL;
        ph->last = NULL;
    }
    return ph;
}

void read_file(head* ph, char* filename) {
    int i;
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!file) {
        printf("File not found\n");
        return;
    }
    char line[256];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
        cr* car = (cr*)malloc(sizeof(cr));
        if (!car) {
            printf("Memory allocation error\n");
            return;
        }
        char* pos = line;
        char* end;
        car->name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 256);
        if (!car->name) {
            printf("Memory allocation error\n");
            return;
        }
        end = strchr(pos, ';');
        strncpy(car->name, pos, end - pos);
        car->name[end - pos] = '\0';
        pos = end + 1;

        car->producer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 256);
        if (!car->producer) {
            printf("Memory allocation error\n");
            return;
        }
        end = strchr(pos, ';');
        strncpy(car->producer, pos, end - pos);
        car->producer[end - pos] = '\0';
        pos = end + 1;

        car->max_load = strtol(pos, &end, 10);
        pos = end + 1;

        car->count_gears = strtol(pos, &end, 10);
        pos = end + 1;

        car->weight = strtof(pos, &end);
        pos = end + 1;

        car->price = strtof(pos, &end);
        pos = end + 1;

        car->max_speed_grear = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * car->count_gears);
        if (!car->max_speed_grear) {
            printf("Memory allocation error\n");
            return;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < car->count_gears; i++) {
            car->max_speed_grear[i] = strtol(pos, &end, 10);
            pos = end + 1;
        }

        car->next = NULL;
        if (!ph->first) {
            ph->first = car;
            ph->last = car;
        } else {
            ph->last->next = car;
            ph->last = car;
        }
        ph->count++;
    }
    fclose(file);
}

void print_cars(head* ph)
{
    cr* curr = ph->first;
    int i = 1, j;

    printf("No. | Car name                 | Car manufacturer      | Maximum load, kg | Count gears | Price, USD  | Maximum speed in each gear\n");
    printf("----|--------------------------|----------------------|------------------|-------------|-------------|--------------------------------------------------------\n");

    while (curr) {
        char car_str[200];
        int k = 0;

        k += snprintf(car_str + k, sizeof(car_str) - k, "%-4d| %-25s| %-21s| %-16d| %-12d| %-12.2f| ", i, curr->name, curr->producer, curr->max_load, curr->count_gears, curr->price);

        for (j = 0; j < curr->count_gears; j++)
            k += snprintf(car_str + k, sizeof(car_str) - k, "%d ", curr->max_speed_grear[j]);

        printf("%s\n", car_str);

        curr = curr->next;
        i++;
    }
}
void remove_by_index(head* ph, int index)
{   cr* prev;
    cr* curr;
    int i;
    if (index < 1 || index > ph->count) {
        printf("Invalid index\n");
        return;
    }
    prev = NULL;
    curr = ph->first;
    i = 1;
    while (curr != NULL && i != index) {
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
        i++;
    }
    if (curr == NULL) {
        printf("Element not found.\n");
        return;
    }
    if (prev == NULL) {
        ph->first = curr->next;
    } else {
        prev->next = curr->next;
    }
    free(curr);
    ph->count--;
}

void reverse_list(head* ph) {
    cr* prev = NULL;
    cr* curr = ph->first;
    cr* next = NULL;
    while (curr) {
        next = curr->next;
        curr->next = prev;
        prev = curr;
        curr = next;
    }
    ph->last = ph->first;
    ph->first = prev;
}

int main() {
    head* ph;
    int index, from_end;
    ph = make_head();
    read_file(ph, "data.txt");
    print_cars(ph);
    printf("Enter the number of the element, counting from the end, that you want to remove:\n");
    scanf("%d", &from_end);
    index = ph->count - from_end + 1;
    if (index < 1 || index > ph->count) {
        printf("Invalid index\n");
    } else {
        printf("\nAfter remove:\n");
        remove_by_index(ph, index);
        print_cars(ph);
    }


    reverse_list(ph);
    printf("\nAfter reverse:\n");
    print_cars(ph);
    return 0;
}
```

Можно попытаться потом очищать память ,изменив main, но это погоды не изменит

```
int main() {
    head* ph;
    int index, from_end;

    ph = make_head();
    read_file(ph, "cars.txt");
    print_cars(ph);

    //удаление элемента списка
    printf("Enter the index of the element to be removed: ");
    scanf("%d", &index);
    remove_by_index(ph, index);
    print_cars(ph);

    //инвертирование списка
    reverse_list(ph);
    print_cars(ph);

    //очистка памяти
    cr* curr = ph->first;
    cr* temp;
    while (curr) {
        temp = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
        free(temp->name);
        free(temp->producer);
        free(temp->max_speed_grear);
        free(temp);
    }
    free(ph);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: при проверке у меня падало если в файле `data.txt` пустые строки. Исправьте это на всякий случай. `if ( strlen ( line ) <= 1 ) continue ;`

Comment: в версии 90 нет комментариев `//` , нельзя определять новые переменные внутри функций, нет функций `strtof` и `snprintf`. Как исправите все предупреждения компилятора, тогда и запашет. `strtof` -> `strtod` ; `snprintf` -> `sprintf` без второго аргумента.

Comment: изменил на strtod и sprintf, теперь всё работает, спасибо. А комментариев в программе нет, добавил , когда писал вопрос, чтобы понятнее код был

Answer (score 0):

В версии 90 нет комментариев `//` , переменные внутри блока нужно определять только в начале `{ }` , нет функций `strtof` и `snprintf`. Как исправите все предупреждения компилятора, тогда и запашет. `strtof` -> `strtod` ; `snprintf` -> `sprintf` без второго аргумента.

Comment: *нельзя определять новые переменные внутри функций* - можно же

Comment: `int i; ++i; int j;` - нельзя. `int i; ++i; { int j; }` - можно. не знаю как это назвать правильно @user7860670

Comment: В C90 определение должно быть в начале блока, а инициализация далее в любой части функции. **Новые переменные в функциях можно определять**.